# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library

Tags: superuser

As you can tell, I'm a newbie to programming, so I just downloaded Java JDK and Eclipse. I installed Java, but every time I open the Eclipse installer, something like this pops up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT7Ky.png

I've tried deleting, uninstalling everything and then installing again but it doesn't work. This is the log file, which I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do:

```
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer (138).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\Users\Neo\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi77E0.tmp\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\152\0\.cp\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    ... 30 more
Root exception:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\Users\Neo\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi77E0.tmp\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\152\0\.cp\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-03-20 00:47:13.753
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer was unable to load class org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer (138).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\Users\Neo\AppData\Local\Temp\eoi77E0.tmp\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\152\0\.cp\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    C:\Users\Neo\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4932r18.dll: Acesso negado

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    ... 30 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core 4 0 2020-03-20 00:47:13.907
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.P2CorePlugin$Implementation.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1885)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1760)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.initializeProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProfileRegistry(AgentImpl.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.load(PersistentMap.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.<init>(AgentImpl.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.addElement(PersistentMap.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.addAgent(AgentManagerImpl.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentManagerImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.load(PersistentMap.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.<init>(AgentManagerImpl.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.<init>(AgentManagerImpl.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core.P2Util.getAgentManager(P2Util.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.P2CorePlugin$Implementation.stop(P2CorePlugin.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:891)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Artifact.<clinit>(CachingRepositoryManager.java:546)
    ... 34 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.initializeProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProvisioningAgent(AgentImpl.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.getProfileRegistry(AgentImpl.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.load(PersistentMap.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl.<init>(AgentImpl.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.createElement(AgentManagerImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.addElement(PersistentMap.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.addAgent(AgentManagerImpl.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentManagerImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl$1.initializeFirstTime(AgentManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.PersistentMap.load(PersistentMap.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.<init>(AgentManagerImpl.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentManagerImpl.<init>(AgentManagerImpl.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core.P2Util.getAgentManager(P2Util.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.P2CorePlugin$Implementation.stop(P2CorePlugin.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1885)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1760)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Artifact.<clinit>(CachingRepositoryManager.java:546)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: “acesso negado”? Is this your personal pc or is it someone else’s who put in restrictions?

Comment: A relative of mine gave it to me, but he didn't program or something. What kind of restriction would it be, and how could I fix it?

Comment: No idea. Can you use a traditional zip distribution of eclipse instead?

Comment: I tried, but the same thing happens.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, but an Eclipse+Windows problem.  You should ask this question on superuser.